# PDF Parsing in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, pdf, core-graphics, quartz-graphics

I am trying to read a PDF on iPhone, I got to know that we can get the info about PDF from CGPDFDocumentGetCatalog method. But, this method returns a CGPDFDictionaryRef. I have browsed through the documentation and didn't find any method to extract its Key/Values. Please help me if anybody has solution for the problem. Or you can tell if we can have any other way to extract data from PDFs.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have to extract the names of the values first. Take a look to [this site](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/WebKit/WebKit-7533.16/mac/WebView/WebPDFDocumentExtras.mm?txt) especially the `allScriptsInPDFDocument` method

Comment: Thanks for your help, but, the libraries and code used their were for MAC OS and are currently unavailable in iPhone OS.

Answer (score 0):

I have just checked out the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGPDFDictionary/Reference/reference.html) and it has a load of functions for getting key value pairs.  If you don't know what the keys are you can use [CGPDFDictionaryApplyFunction](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGPDFDictionary/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000965-CH1g-BAJEGHAG) to with an appropriate callback.

Alternatively, check out the [PDF Specification](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf) for a detailed description of the catalog (section 7.7.2).

Comment: Hi Jeremy, thanks for your help. But now a new problem have cropped up. I am getting error while creating content stream. See the following line: -

myContentStream = CGPDFContentStreamCreateWithPage(myPage);

Can you help me in this case.

Comment: Sorry, you need to give more context e.g. what is the specific error.